# Event for "mouse over" when user hovers mouse pointer over row in Grid or Table in Vaadin 7?

Tags: hover, vaadin, vaadin7

Does either the Grid or Table widget in Vaadin 7 let me know when the user hovers the mouse pointer over a row?

I want to react to row hover, such as showing an image and switching the image for each particular row on which the user is pointing with the mouse pointer.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what should exactly happen when you hover an element.

1. Maybe you could use a `ItemDescriptionGenerator` like @Nebras already pointed out on another answer
2. Just use a standard css :hover selector to change background image (or some other attribute) of an element.
3. Use [Mouse Event Extension](https://github.com/vaadin-marcus/mouse-events) to listen mouse over and mouse out events on your server-side code. But you must be very careful with this one to avoid generating too much requests. **UPDATE** This add-on was withdrawn by its author. [Source code available](https://github.com/vaadin-marcus/mouse-events).

Comment: The link for “Mouse Event Extension” fails. Is that add-on pulled from the directory? Or renamed?

Comment: Author removed the addon because there were some issues with it, however its source codes are still available here: https://github.com/vaadin-marcus/mouse-events

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ItemDescriptionGenerator and create your own custom description (tooltip) for each row, check [this](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.features.html#components.features.description). you can add rich tooltip.

Comment: mark it as an answer if you get what you want, or add new comment to help more ;)